# Codeigniter Routing with PCRE

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, pcre

I am trying to create a routing rule in my Codeigniter installation which uses PCRE.

What I am trying to match is this

http://example.com/segment1/segment2/(capturethis)

So I can use the "capturethis" portion as an input for the method.  I only want to make this match if "segment1" is not "admin".  There may be any number of segments.  I usually represent a segment as `([^/]*)`, so anything other than a "/" while using "/" in between each `([^/]*)`.

At first I was thinking of writing an expression which did not match "admin" or "/" with something like `[^[\/|admin]\/]*([^\/]*)` but had no luck.

After looking around I believe this might be achieved using a Negative Lookbehind, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this. I was trying to do something like this
`^(?<!/|i/admin/)[/([^/]*)]*` but that would leave me with potentially an unknown amount of captured segments and I would always need the last without knowing how many there are.

Has anyone done this before or knows how to do this?  I'm sure I'm over looking something simple, but am not as fluent in regex as I'd like to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

Thank you for your update on how Codeigniter handles routes..I think we should be on the same page now.  The `^` character only has special meanings in character classes and won't have the affect you expect in the lookarounds..also, it shouldn't be necessary since we are already using a negative lookahead (`(?!...)`).  However, as you said, `(?!admin)([^/]*)` still has some issues since `[^/]*` will match `dmin` because when we are at the character `d` it is not followed by `admin`.  To solve this, we want to do a positive lookbehind assertion also.  This will make sure we are either right after the beginning of the string or a forward slash (`d` wouldn't match in this case, since it is right after `a`):

```
(?!admin)(?<=^|/)([^/]*)
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/fN2kT4)

---

You can't throw `admin` in your character class like you would think, since it will just look for `a`, `d`, `m`, `i`, or `n`.  However, you were close with the negative lookarounds.  The key is to remember that these are *zero-width assertions* and do not match any characters.  In this case we want to use a negative lookahead. This is because as we begin to match a new segment following a `/`, we want to make sure that from that point on (*ahead*) `admin` is not matched..if it isn't matched, then we can continue to capture `([^/]*)` like you typically do.

I'm not well versed in codeigniter, so this may not be exactly what you need to use in your routing..but this should show you how everything works:

```
/(?!admin)([^/]*)
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/jN7wT4)

Comment: This is close to what I am trying to do.  I supposed I should have mention in codeigniter the string being parse is everything after the domain name for routes, so `segment1/segment2/(capturethis)` Is there a way to kind of "break" out of the regex or return false if the string starts with "admin"?  If the word "admin" occurs elsewhere in the string that is okay. I've modified what you have to `(?!^admin)([^/]*)` but as you stated it is reading it as `a`, `d`, `m`, `i`, `n`.  Here is a link http://regex101.com/r/fJ0gW3 .  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you again for all of your help.  I've played around with what you updated to try and capture only the last segment rather than all segments except for the first.  This is what I came up with, but no luck. http://regex101.com/r/fN4dM3 .  So if the first segment starts with /admin return false otherwise capture the last segment so I can use it with $1 (or $2 so long as the last segment will always be the same number)

Comment: I was trying to use a negative lookahead to check if there were anymore characters after matching 0 or more characters of any kind (except `/`) which is followed by 0 or 1 (`/`).  I placed a (`.*`) after verifing `admin` is not at the beginning but before trying to match the last segment.

Comment: @d.lanza38 check out [this demo/explanation](http://regex101.com/r/vA4qR1).  This works because there is one capture group repeated.  RegEx will always end up capturing the last instance of the repetition.

Comment: Right on the money!  Thank you so much for your help.  In the mean time I had come up with this http://regex101.com/r/iT2zG2 but it always captured the last element regardless if it started with "admin".  I had added a precaution in it to catch if the string started with just "admin" and not "administrative-offices" or other potentially legitimate pages.  I'll try to carry over the same precaution and post if I am successful.  Thank you again.

Comment: No worries, and I think you are over-thinking the `administrative-offices` issue.  Our negative lookahead makes sure the word `admin` is not at the beginning of the string, all we need to do is make sure `admin/` is not at the beginning of the string: [demo](http://regex101.com/r/tL9gO4)

Comment: Well if that first string is "administrative-offices" such as this: http://regex101.com/r/rA9jH2 it would not capture.  Depending the the site structure on the front end it is a possibility.